# PHP-Codeigniter string encrypt and decrypt

Tags: php, encryption, codeigniter-2, session-cookies

In one web application in CI, they used to save COOKIE data as an encrypted form and retrieve by decrypting it. Its was working fine since "GoDaddy" blocked "base64_encode" due to some security reasons ( Don't know why ). This is the error which I got

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: base64_decode() has been disabled for security reasons
Filename: models/extras.php
Line Number: 196
```

My encrypt and decrypt code as follows. Is there any alternate method for doing the same with out "base64_encode" ?

```
function encodeString($str){
  for($i=0; $i<5;$i++)
  {
    $str=strrev(base64_encode($str)); //apply base64 first and then reverse the string
  }
  return $str;
}

function decodeString($str){
  for($i=0; $i<5;$i++)
  {
    $str=base64_decode(strrev($str)); //apply base64 first and then reverse the string}
   }
   return $str;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Wat? What harebrained reason could there be for disabling such a benign yet essential function?!

Comment: @ramesh You have to ask you Hosting Provider to enable those function or Change your hosting provider. It is dependent on you.

Comment: Yea .. I requested in hosting provider its "GoDaddy" ... They said they can't accept "base64_encode", I already purchased the server for 2 years and its 1.5year left.. they wont refund

Answer (score 1):

In order to eliminate this error message you need to do ONE of the following things:

- Remove the base64_decode string from the disable_functions at php.ini* file
- Ask your hosting provider to remove the string above if you don't have an access to the php.ini* file
- Change hosting provider which allows the running of the base64_decode function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data =array(           

 'password'    => md5($this->input->post('password')),

);
```